# Aligning containers top and center

Tags: flutter, dart

I want my first container to be aligned to the top of the page and the other two containers to be aligned in the center of the page automatically (So that it is centered no matter how big the screen).

I basically want it to kind of look like this image with one part on top and the others centered.

(https://i.stack.imgur.com/UBi45.png)

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class HomeScreen extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        backgroundColor: Colors.white,
        elevation: 0.0,
        title: Row(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
          children: <Widget>[
            Padding(
              padding: const EdgeInsets.only(right: 60.0), // Centering Ing
              child: Image.asset(
                'assets/logo.png',
                height: 20,
              ),
            ),
            SizedBox(width: 8),
            Text(
              '',
              style: TextStyle(
                color: Colors.black,
                fontSize: 20,
              ),
            ),
          ],
        ),
        centerTitle: true, // Center the title text within the AppBar
      ),
      body: Column(
        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
        children: [
          Align(
            alignment: Alignment.topCenter,
            child: Container(
              margin: EdgeInsets.all(20),
              color: Colors.amber,
              child: const Text(
                'Test1',
                textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                style: TextStyle(
                  fontSize: 60,
                  fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                ),
              ),
            ),
          ),
          SizedBox(height: 100), // Adjust the height as needed
          Center(
            child: Container(
              color: Colors.blue,
              child: const Text(
                'Test2',
                textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                style: TextStyle(
                  fontSize: 60,
                  fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                ),
              ),
            ),
          ),
          SizedBox(height: 8), // Adjust the height as needed
          Center(
            child: Container(
              color: Colors.red,
              child: const Text(
                'Test3',
                textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                style: TextStyle(
                  fontSize: 60,
                  fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                ),
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use stack instead of column to achieve the desired layout

```
 body: Stack(
    children: [
      Align(
        alignment: Alignment.topCenter,
        child: Container(
          margin: const EdgeInsets.all(20),
          color: Colors.amber,
          child: const Text(
            'Test1',
            textAlign: TextAlign.center,
            style: TextStyle(
              fontSize: 60,
              fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ),
      Center(
        child: Column(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
          crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
          children: [
            Container(
              color: Colors.blue,
              child: const Text(
                'Test2',
                textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                style: TextStyle(
                  fontSize: 60,
                  fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                ),
              ),
            ),
            const SizedBox(height: 8), // Adjust the height as needed
            Container(
              color: Colors.red,
              child: const Text(
                'Test3',
                textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                style: TextStyle(
                  fontSize: 60,
                  fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                ),
              ),
            )
          ],
        ),
      )
    ],
  ),
```